# elasticsearch query returns more than hits

Tags: python, elasticsearch

my indexing python file below
there should be seven hit that matches the query based on the real data, but it keeps producing 10 results. because default size parameter is 10
Is there any way to let it produce as much as the number of the hits not the size? or do i have to anticipate the size and put it in the query all the time?

result:

[image: {"took":34,"timed_out":false,"_shards":{"total":5,"successful":5,"skipped":0,"failed":0},"hits":{"total":26639,"max_score":41.454712,"hits":[{"_index":"hscate","_type":"my-type","_id":"X2dEPWkBr1fwmDIlIxgl","_score":41.454712,"_source":{"date":"20190224","company":"kshop","Category":"의류","name":"추성훈의 코몽트 기모본딩바지 3+1종_총 4종","url":"/i?id=8853152&from=web_timeline","price":"38,900원"}},{"_index":"hscate","_type":"my-type","_id":"j0xpPWkB71e3cHDPkRNQ","_score":41.454712,"_source":{"date":"20190215","company":"kshop","Category":"의류","name":"추성훈의 코몽트 기모본딩바지 3+1종_총 4종","url":"/i?id=8841273&from=web_timeline","price":"89,100원"}},{"_index":"hscate","_type":"my-type","_id":"dWhLPWkBr1fwmDIlYUcG","_score":41.454712,"_source":{"date":"20190131","company":"kshop","Category":"의류","name":"추성훈의 코몽트 기모본딩바지 3+1종_총 4종","url":"/i?id=8822592&from=web_timeline","price":"88,900원"}},{"_index":"hscate","_type":"my-type","_id":"cWhLPWkBr1fwmDIlXzFS","_score":41.454712,"_source":{"date":"20190215","company":"kshop","Category":"의류","name":"추성훈의 코몽트 기모본딩바지 3+1종_총 4종","url":"/i?id=8841273&from=web_timeline","price":"89,100원"}},{"_index":"hscate","_type":"my-type","_id":"XUtpPWkB71e3cHDPYfuO","_score":41.454712,"_source":{"date":"20190201","company":"kshop","Category":"의류","name":"추성훈의 코몽트 기모본딩바지 3+1종_총 4종","url":"/i?id=8826970&from=web_timeline","price":"59,000원"}},{"_index":"hscate","_type":"my-type","_id":"qk12PWkB71e3cHDPnC0o","_score":41.454712,"_source":{"date":"20190205","company":"kshop","Category":"의류","name":"추성훈의 코몽트 기모본딩바지 3+1종_총 4종","url":"/i?id=8831200&from=web_timeline","price":"78,900원"}},{"_index":"hscate","_type":"my-type","_id":"p013PWkB71e3cHDPynjZ","_score":41.454712,"_source":{"date":"20190215","company":"kshop","Category":"의류","name":"추성훈의 코몽트 기모본딩바지 3+1종_총 4종","url":"/i?id=8841273&from=web_timeline","price":"89,100원"}},{"_index":"hscate","_type":"my-type","_id":"CE13PWkB71e3cHDPf2KA","_score":41.454712,"_source":{"date":"20190131","company":"kshop","Category":"의류","name":"추성훈의 코몽트 기모본딩바지 3+1종_총 4종","url":"/i?id=8822592&from=web_timeline","price":"88,900원"}},{"_index":"hscate","_type":"my-type","_id":"xE13PWkB71e3cHDPfD7b","_score":41.454712,"_source":{"date":"20190224","company":"kshop","Category":"의류","name":"추성훈의 코몽트 기모본딩바지 3+1종_총 4종","url":"/i?id=8853152&from=web_timeline","price":"38,900원"}},{"_index":"hscate","_type":"my-type","_id":"iU14PWkB71e3cHDPhZxt","_score":41.454712,"_source":{"date":"20190221","company":"kshop","Category":"의류","name":"추성훈의 코몽트 기모본딩바지 3+1종_총 4종","url":"/i?id=8848822&from=web_timeline","price":"138,000원"}}]}}]

maybe related to how i indexed it? idk why hits total is 26639. it should match like 7.

```
from elasticsearch import  helpers, Elasticsearch
from datetime import datetime
import csv
import json

es = Elasticsearch()

with open('result.csv', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    helpers.bulk(es, reader, index='hscate', doc_type='my-type')

res = es.search(index = 'hscate',
            doc_type = 'my-type',
           # size ='1000',
            #from_=0,
                body = {
                'query': {     
                    'match' : {
                         'name' : '추성훈의 코몽트 기모본딩바지 3+1종_총 4종'
                    }
                }
            })
print(len(res['hits']['hits']))
with open('mycsvfile.csv', 'w',encoding='utf-8',newline='') as f:  # Just use 'w' mode in 3.x
    header_present  = False
    for doc in res['hits']['hits']:
        my_dict = doc['_source'] 
        if not header_present:
            w = csv.DictWriter(f, my_dict.keys())
            w.writeheader()
            header_present = True
        w.writerow(my_dict)
```

Comment: What does the print line actually prints?

Comment: @dadoonet I've attached response of the query,  print(len) always print the size parameter of query. that means hit is always greater than size

Comment: Maybe use pagination

Comment: You have 26639 hits that matches your query. Not sure why you are saying that only one hit match.

Comment: Also your query is wrong to me. You cannot have 2 match clauses like this. This must be wrap in a bool query.

Comment: @dadoonet yeah i know, but in the actual data in csv that i crawled, there's only 7 rows that name matches that

Comment: The example you shown is incorrect. Share the real query.

Comment: I've edited with real parameter value, Idk why hits 26639 man, there is like 7 tuples that match in real data and as u can see one of 20190224 one is duplicate. csv only contains 11428 rows too

Comment: Most likely you imported your CSV multiple times. But that's another question.

Comment: The name field probably uses a default analyzer. Which splits into terms. Each term is than searched individually (it's a OR query by default). If you need exact match, use a keyword analyzer instead and a term query.

Comment: @dadoonet i changed to term query it stays same, I think its related to indexing. is there a better way to import csv in es with python?

Comment: That's what I said. You need to change the analyzer. This is an index settings. I'm going to share an example as an answer.

Comment: yeah i cant attach a code as a comment i've tried to use keyword analyzer like 
  body = {
    'settings':{
        'analysis':{
            'analyzer' : 'keyword'
                }
    }  
} and added this to bulk(_source=body) , no change

Comment: but yeah plz share an example, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the discussion we have as comments, I can now understand what you meant and what your actual problem is.

When you are using the defaults in elasticsearch, elasticsearch is analyzing your text with a [standard analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.6/analysis-standard-analyzer.html) which basically splits your text into tokens.
When you search then on that field with a [match query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.6/query-dsl-match-query.html), the same analysis process is applied. Which means that your query text is also broken into tokens.
The `match` query runs a "or" on all generated tokens.

The following example that you can copy and paste in Kibana developer Console shows that:

```
DELETE test
PUT test 
PUT test/_doc/1
{
  "name": "추성훈의 코몽트 기모본딩바지 3+1종_총 4종"
}
PUT test/_doc/2
{
  "name": "추성훈의 기모본딩바지 4종"
}
GET test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "name": "추성훈의 코몽트 기모본딩바지 3+1종_총 4종"
    }
  }
}
```

It gives the following result:

```
{
  "took" : 12,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 2,
    "max_score" : 1.7260926,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "test",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "1",
        "_score" : 1.7260926,
        "_source" : {
          "name" : "추성훈의 코몽트 기모본딩바지 3+1종_총 4종"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "test",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "2",
        "_score" : 0.8630463,
        "_source" : {
          "name" : "추성훈의 기모본딩바지 4종"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

If you did not define any analyzer in your index settings, then probably elasticsearch generated a `.keyword` subfield which is not analyzed.
You can query it like:

```
GET test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "name.keyword": "추성훈의 코몽트 기모본딩바지 3+1종_총 4종"
    }
  }
}
```

This now gives only exact matches:

```
{
  "took" : 3,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "max_score" : 0.2876821,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "test",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "1",
        "_score" : 0.2876821,
        "_source" : {
          "name" : "추성훈의 코몽트 기모본딩바지 3+1종_총 4종"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

If you know that you are never going to run full text search but only exact match, that you don't need to aggregate or sort on the `name` field, then you can define your index as follows:

```
DELETE test
PUT test 
{
  "mappings": {
    "_doc": {
      "properties": {
        "name": {
          "type": "text",
          "analyzer": "keyword"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
PUT test/_doc/1
{
  "name": "추성훈의 코몽트 기모본딩바지 3+1종_총 4종"
}
PUT test/_doc/2
{
  "name": "추성훈의 기모본딩바지 4종"
}
GET test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "name": "추성훈의 코몽트 기모본딩바지 3+1종_총 4종"
    }
  }
}
```

This also gives one single result and requires less space on disk than the default behavior.

Comment: Thank you very much for the details. I want to put settings into the bulk() but I can't. guess python es client should specify the size all the time. thanks for the answer tho.

Comment: No you can't. Bulk is made to send data to elasticsearch. Not to create an index. Those are different APIs. Bulk just replace `PUT test/_doc/x` calls.

Comment: thanks for the reply, mind  sharing some edit on python script i provded? that would be more accurate since i don't use PUT, GET calls. Im trying to use python client Its totally fine if its too much.

Comment: No. I'm not a Python developer. But I believe you need to use https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/api.html#elasticsearch.client.IndicesClient.create

Comment: I was being so dumb, i put bulk as many times as i used query, that's why it has so many contents. thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

As you suspect, I think elasticsearch will simply produce 10 results for you, based on the rank that they produce when matching them in your data.

Try this:

```
body = {
    'from': 0,
    'size': 1,
    'query': {
        'bool': {
            'must': [
                {
                    'match': {
                        'Category' : 'category name',
                    }
                },
                {
                    'match' : {
                        'name' : 'product name'
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Source: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-from-size.html